# http multipart response and boundary

Tags: http

I am thinking to use HTTP multipart to return a dynamically generated binary stream (such as an mp4 video clip), followed by a signature file and then other contents to a client in one single HTTP response message. In my case, the size of the mp4 (the first part of the response message) is unknow when building the http header fields so I can't set Content-Length for the mp4 part. I will need to use multipart boundary to separate each part. However I was advised that if the boundary string appears in the mp4 data, the multipart wouldn't work. Other people suggested to encode each part (such as BASE64 encoding) so that I can choose a boundary with non-BASE64 characters which will never appear inside any part of the http response. The issue is that BASE64 would increase size by 33% which is an overhead we can't accept. 
The question is:
Is there a way to workaround this? Have I missed something? or May be you know a better way to do it (we have to return several parts in one single HTTP response)?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the client understands the message format you can always strip the boundary string, so you wouldn't have a problem there.

You will need to remember the boundary-string and look for it's end-piece it in the data-stream and only forward the data to the player that comes between those parts.

Comment: the bounday string is sent to the client at the beginnging as HTTP header fields, and yes, the client should undertand it. The issue is that if the boundary appears in the body of the "part", it will be treated as a boundary which is wrong.